# Behavior of Tomcat clustering while the server is down or shutdown

Tags: tomcat, liferay, tomcat7, session-replication

Let's assume I have two Tomcat (version 7 bundled in Liferay) servers on two different machine. They are connected to a load balancer (in my case PEN) and configured for clustering and session replication with static membership.

From Tomcat clustering perspective is there any difference between the following common situations:

- When one of the Tomcat instance is shutdown.
- When one of the
  server is disconnected from the network. (meaning the live instance
  cannot ping to it).

In the other word does it matter to the live Tomcat instance which situation is faced?

Thanks in advance